# Execute with system function results in error of `undefined variable`

Tags: vimscript

```
  execute "normal! :echo ". system('echo hello')
```

The above results in:

```
E121: Undefined variable: hello
```

Why? I'm expecting it to evaluate as:

```
  execute "normal! :echo hello"
```

Comment: I can reproduce this, though the chain of logic leads me to conclude with the OP that this is odd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

First of all, you want to run an ex command, so you don't need the `:norm!` command to execute an **ex** command. A simple `:echo` works. 
(In fact, you can and probably should get rid of the `:exe` command and use `:echo` directly, but I'll come back to this later).

Second, if you want to see what will be executed, use `:echo` instead of `:exe`. So this:

```
echo ":echo ". system('echo hello')
```

will output `:echo hello`. So what is the problem here? Have a look at the documentation at [:h :echo](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#:echo)

> ```
> :ec[ho] {expr1} ..      Echoes each {expr1}, with a space in between.  The
> ```

Note the word `expr1`. So `:echo` expects an expression. What that means is, either a variable, or a **quoted** string (or some other special types like numbers, options, etc, see again the help at [:h expression-syntax](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expression-syntax)).

However, the way `hello` is used, `:echo` expects it to be a variable. But Vim cannot find a variable called `hello`, because it does not exist. So try this:

```
 :let g:hello='Hello my dear'
 :exe ':echo ' system('echo hello')
 Hello my dear
```

Note, since you are using string concatenation, to concatenate the output of the `system()` function with the `:echo` command. However, if you get rid of the indirection and simply use

```
:echo system('echo hello')
```

you can see directly the result of the echo system command. Because in this case, echo knows that the `system('echo hello')` command is a correct expression and it will simply output the result.

Comment: Is there some way I can quote / escape the value from `system`  without having to use a intermediate variable?

Comment: You mean like this? `exe ":echo ". string(system('echo hello'))` But why keep this additional indirection? That sounds silly.

Comment: Hmm, I should have explained that the `echo 'hello'` is just a placeholder / minimal example, instead I'm getting the output from a command that returns a filepath.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski  Understood. The question is more like: *Why do you need `:exe ":echo"`. Why not use `:echo` directly?*

Comment: Debugging purposes. Unless you mean I can run any of the `:theseCommands` normally within VimScript?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski `:thoseCommands` are technically VimScript commands. They can used as is, no need to put them into `:exe` calls.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is not in the first command, but in the second.

If you just run the Ex command directly, you get the same E121 error about undefined variable:

```
:echo hello
E121: Undefined variable: hello
```

So what's wrong with the second command? Well, you're missing a `<CR>` there to actually execute the command.

As [`:help :normal`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal) states:

> `{commands}` should be a complete command.  If `{commands}` does not finish a command, **the last one will be aborted as if `<Esc>` or `<C-C>` was typed.**  This implies that an insert command must be completed.  **A ":" command must be completed as well.**

You can reproduce the same error with:

```
:execute "normal! :echo hello\<CR>"
E121: Undefined variable: hello
```

This is actually equivalent to the command that uses `system()`, since `system()` will actually preserve the newline added by the `echo` command. You can see that with:

```
:echo strtrans(system('echo hello'))
hello^@
```

(`^@` is normally a NUL byte, but it's how Vim represents a newline internally. If you just `:echo` the result of that `system()` command you will notice a newline at the end, just it's not as visible as with `strtrans()` since it's, well, a newline.)

So all in all this error is expected, it's only omitted from your second example because that Ex command is being cancelled as it's incomplete.

Comment: These were my initial thoughts... oddly i concluded that concatenating the strings would work and i dont know why. Hm.